# Trying to style element conditionally

Tags: reactjs

```
const x = [{text: "asdf", isActive: true},{text: "qwer", isActive: false},{text: "zxcv", isActive: false}]

...
render() {
  return (
    {x.map(y => <p>{y.text}</p>)}
  )
}
```

If `isActive` is true, then I want the paragraph tag to have a strike-through, but if it is false then it should be left as is. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ternary operator like this.

```js
const x = [{text: "asdf", isActive: true},{text: "qwer", isActive: false},{text: "zxcv", isActive: false}]

...
render() {
  return (
    {x.map({ text, isActive } => <p style={{ textDecoration: isActive ? "line-through" : "none" }}>{y.text}</p>)}
  )
}
```

Comment: So would the `?` mean that if it is truthy then do the following thing

Comment: If condition is true, then return the thing that is just after `?` otherwise return the thing that is just after `:`.